# MVC 3 PartialView Form - Submit changes URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a MVC 3 project that has a simple form which is contained in a PartialView:
(form is in "`<div id="form"> </div>`" in the View that is loading this partial

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Form", new AjaxOptions
                                                           {
                                                               HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                               UpdateTargetId = "form"
                                                           }))
{ .... }
```

My controller is:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Submit(FormElement form)
    {
 ....
  return PartialView("_RequestFormSubmitted");
    }
```

Issue I have is when I submit the form, I get directed to the view result URL (/Form/Submit/) instead of staying on the current page, and having the Partial View returned.

Am I missing something very obvious? 
Could I be missing a script reference maybe?

I am including the following scripts at the end of the page:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Edit:

My form is now getting rendered as follows in the HTML

```
<form action="/Form/Submit" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#form" id="form0" method="post">    <hgroup>
        <h6 class="icon"><img src="/Content/img/icon/dining.png"> YOUR<br>DINING<br>REQUEST</h6>
    </hgroup>
<ul>

    <li class="field type-select">
        <label for="Name">Your name</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Your name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Right, solved it: I didn't include

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(I had the "non-ajax one however!")

Thanks for everyone's help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

`new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "listForm" }`

on your submit link

Comment: I updated my Ajax options on the Form, and I still had the same issue. You say on your submit link however? Should I add the ajax options to my submit button?

Comment: you should have a div with `listForm`. and you need to use link button on something clickable

Comment: Form submitted with   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> - Form surrounded by <div class="form" id="form" name="form"> (added both id and name to be sure) the div is outside the form. However, I've just tried added the div inside the form, and it still goes to a new page.

Comment: my updatedTargetId = "" matches the Id of my div btw.. I know I've gone from "listForm" to "form"